# How to solve CORS request did not succeed in express.js when react client try fetch data?

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I done so many changes in `app.js` file to solve this issue `CORS request did not succeed` but i always facing the same issue.How to solve this issue. I added my app.js code please check anyone. thanks

app.js Code

```
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');

const userlogin   = require('./routes/User_route');
const deviceRoutes = require("./routes/Device_route");

app.use('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4007);
app.set('host', "*.*.*.*"); 

app.use("/users",userlogin);
app.use("/users", deviceRoutes);
module.exports = app;
```

Error

> TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
>   bundle.js:132447:16
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:4007/users/login. (Reason:
>   CORS request did not succeed).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood that time. Thanks for informing me. @GhostCat

Comment: You are very welcome. I appreciate the quick and kind comeback, and I assume you will be more careful in the future and you will create many better votes ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try adding a middleware to handle CORS.

```
//CORS middleware
var corsMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost'); //replace localhost with actual host
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization');

    next();
}

app.use(corsMiddleware);
```

Comment: after login no data is received by client.same Error

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how is this setup ? Where is the server running? Where is the client running? Are you using postman or browser to do the api call?

Comment: I am using browser and postman both , In postman this error will not occur but for browser it's always. Both server and client are running in different PC.

Comment: If you are running client and server on different PCs, ensure that in this line `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost')` localhost is replaced by the IP of the client PC.

Comment: If I specify IP of client then It will restrict the no of client. I can't specify any client IP because client IP will change every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cors npm in express.

```
npm install cors
```

Update app.js

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```