# CORS issue in express.js project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I am trying to develop a MERN project. My code in `server.js` file of `express.js` is like below.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const addressroute = require('./api/routes/address');
const userroute = require('./api/routes/user');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/addresses', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;

var cors = require('cors');


let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended:true } ));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api/address', addressroute);
app.use('/api/users', userroute);
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

I installed CORS using `npm install cors --save` this command.

I am getting below error.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/api/users/register. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/api/users/register. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve CORS request did not succeed in express.js when react client try fetch data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361226/how-to-solve-cors-request-did-not-succeed-in-express-js-when-react-client-try-fe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `cors` above your routes:

```
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended:true } ));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api/address', addressroute);
app.use('/api/users', userroute);
app.listen(PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code snippet:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try to use the following code   
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the CORS middleware (`app.use(cors());`) to be executed before you define your routes. In the snippet that you added here, the CORS middleware is not invoked on each request

Answer (score 0):

Cors should be enabled or included before your routes.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const addressroute = require('./api/routes/address');
const userroute = require('./api/routes/user');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/addresses', { useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;



let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended:true } ));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use('/api/address', addressroute);
app.use('/api/users', userroute);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Answer (score -1):

while calling your api from frontend add
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
in headers of request.

Comment: Maybe you're referring to the Origin header, but this is not what causing the error that the OP mentioned here