# MERN stack user registration form not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

Getting 404 error on MERN stack

Description:

I am getting a 404 error when I try to access my MERN stack application. I have checked all of the possible reasons for the error and I am still not able to figure out what is causing it.

Here is the code I am using:
JavaScript

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const logger = require("morgan");
const connectDB = require("./config/database");
const mainRoutes = require("./routes/main");
const postRoutes = require("./routes/posts");
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
//Use .env file in config folder
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config/.env" });

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

//Connect To Database
connectDB();

//Using EJS for views
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//Static Folder
app.use(express.static("public"));

//Body Parsing
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

//Logging
app.use(logger("dev"));

//Use forms for put / delete
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

// Setup Sessions - stored in MongoDB
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
  })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Use flash messages for errors, info, ect...
app.use(flash());

//Setup Routes For Which The Server Is Listening
app.use("/", mainRoutes);
app.use("/post", postRoutes);


//Server Running
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server is running, you better catch it!");
});

routes=>main.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const authController = require("../controllers/auth");
const homeController = require("../controllers/home");
const postsController = require("../controllers/posts");
const { ensureAuth } = require("../middleware/auth");

//Main Routes 
router.get("/", homeController.getIndex);
router.get("/profile", ensureAuth, postsController.getProfile);

//Routes for user login/signup
router.get("/login", authController.getLogin);
router.post("/login", authController.postLogin);
router.get("/logout", authController.logout);
router.get("/signup", authController.getSignup);
router.post("/signup", authController.postSignup);

module.exports = router;
```

FRONTEND REACT JS CODE:

```
const RegistrationForm = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Create a FormData object to send the form data
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('password', password);
    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('address', address);

    // Send the form data to the backend
    fetch('/signup', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          console.log('Form submitted successfully');
          // Reset the form fields
          setName('');
          setPassword('');
          setImage(null);
          setAddress('');
        } else {
          console.error('Error submitting form');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Network error:', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>User Registration</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Image:</label>
          <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Address:</label>
          <textarea value={address} onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegistrationForm;
```

I have checked the following:

- The URL to make sure I am entering it correctly.
- I have tried refreshing the page.

I am still getting a 404 error.

Can anyone help me figure out what is causing the error?

Comment: Can you change the api url from `/signup` to `http://ip:port/signup` and check ?

Comment: Changed it, now I am getting an error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://ip:5000/signup. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Comment: Firstly try fix CORS error. It might start your application up.

Comment: imported CORS Module in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass complete url in fetch instead of just `/signup`.

Assuming you're running your app on `local server` and on port `4000`, endpoint you should be hitting is `http://localhost:4000/signup`

Simply update your fetch method to this

```
// Send the form data to the backend
fetch('http://localhost:4000/signup', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
})
```

Check this for cors error

[How to solve CORS request did not succeed in express.js when react client try fetch data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361226/how-to-solve-cors-request-did-not-succeed-in-express-js-when-react-client-try-fe)

Comment: It's returning this error: 
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/signup. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).